# The links in the top bar have vanished

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The Stackexchange link at the top left still remains, but I no longer see the

```
Rory Alsop 10,020 2.6.42 | tools | chat | meta | faq
```

This is true on both main and meta security.

The top bar appears correctly on at least 18 other StackExchange sites I have just tried.

Am running on IE7 - will try later from my normal Chrome and FF

Comment: you sure? I see em... looks ok to me. But then, maybe it's just my super-alpha-rendering...

Comment: wonder if it's IE7 that's the problem

Comment: nope - can't be. All the other SE sites have it

Comment: could be the CSS for this design is incompatible with IE7

Comment: IE7...? you mean, IE **9**, right...?

Comment: Nope - definitely 7. It's not my laptop, alright...

Comment: @Jeff - it did work yesterday after go-live, and I did test by force-reloading then. First fail was 6 hours ago - not worked since.

Comment: I have the same issue also on IE7, works on other StackExchange sites but not the new design here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We [rolled out a new top bar last year](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/), so I doubt very much that this bug still obtains.

Answer (score 2):

Have tested with FF4 and 5, IE8 and Chrome.

Confirmed it is an IE7 specific issue with the new CSS here, so probably comes under the not supported-no fix expected heading?